# How to export git file with ignore folder

Tags: git

```
git archive --format zip -- output ~/Desktop/file.zip master
```

This is how I export my git project, it will not export file or folder which in .gitignore file, but if it's possible to export a specific file or folder like

```
git archive --format zip --include vendor/ -- output ~/Desktop/file.zip master
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you must first mark the folders or files you don't want to put into the archive with `export-ignore` in the repo's `.gitattributes`:

```
/src export-ignore
/build export-ignore
/test export-ignore
/.git* export-ignore
```

Then you can call `git archive` with `--worktree-attributes` to ignore the specified files.

See: [git archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)